# Are there any command line utilities which can calculate and/or limit how fast a pipe is running?

Tags: linux, bandwidth

I'm doing some basic stress testing of a Linux kernel network IWF with netcat. The set-up is fairly simple. On the target side:

```
nc -l -p 10000 > /dev/null
```

And on my desktop I was running:

```
cat /dev/urandom | nc 192.168.0.20 10000
```

I'm using urandom for some poor-mans fuzz testing. However I find that even at this rate I can break something quite quickly.

**EDIT**

So I've been playing with trickle to rate limit how fast I'm generating data:

```
cat /dev/urandom | trickle -u 10 nc 192.168.0.20 10000
```

But it's hard to tell if this is working. What would be really useful is a the pv equivilent of trickle that can work with pipes.

Comment: just search for `pv` in your repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Straight after posting I came across a tool called "Pipe Viewer" which seems to be just what I need. http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml